# How to give Horizontal ScrollView inside the Drawerlayout in Android Studio using XML?

Tags: xml, android-studio

In my app I want to give Horizontal ScrollView inside the Drawerlayout in Android Studio using XML. I have tried something in android studio along with XML. Here i want it as static only. And also I don't want it in using Java. Because i am going to fix the count of button. My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:measureAllChildren="false"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorGrapeFruit"
                android:id="@+id/specialistlayout">

                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button One" />
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button One" />
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button One" />
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button One" />
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button One" />
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button One" />
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button One" />
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button One" />
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button One" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_homepage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_homepage"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_homepage_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But this code not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to lock the drawer layout when the drawer is open. Does the drawer itself move when trying to scroll?

If so, then maybe you need to call the following in `onDrawerOpened`

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
```

Let me know what you have done in your class file too!

Comment: Hi... this will lock my Drawer only. Still facing the same as issue as mentioned above